# DB transaction using R2BC Kotlin coroutine

Tags: kotlin, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, reactive, kotlin-coroutines

I using R2bc in Spring Webflux project with Kotlin. It is working nicely. But I have this method

```
@Component
class UserRepository(private val client: DatabaseClient, private val operator: TransactionalOperator) {

    suspend fun updateUser(user: User, value: String): Int {

        client.execute("INSERT INTO log(user_id, activity) VALUES (:user_id, :activity)")
              .bind("activity", user.activity)
              .bind("user_id", user.id)
              .fetch()
              .awaitRowsUpdated()

        return client.execute("UPDATE users SET value = :value WHERE id = :id")
                     .bind("value", value)
                     .bind("id", user.id)
                     .fetch()
                     .awaitRowsUpdated()
}
```

This method is working but I would like to use DB transaction. Is it supported in Kotlin.

Comment: why are you using the database client and not spring-data repositories?

Comment: Because I need to manage several entities in one method. This one is much simplified version there are few that are more involved. But we do use R2BC repo in most simpler use cases.

Comment: because this awaitRowsUpdated is blocking

Comment: Even if you call from suspended method. I don’t think so can you show me any examples.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok I found the solution I am posting it here so that other can benefit from it. All I had to do was.

```
@Component
class UserRepository(private val client: DatabaseClient, private val operator: TransactionalOperator) {

    suspend fun updateUser(user: User, value: String) =

        operator.executeAndAwait {

            client.execute("INSERT INTO log(user_id, activity) VALUES (:user_id, :activity)")
                  .bind("activity", user.activity)
                  .bind("user_id", user.id)
                  .await()

            client.execute("UPDATE users SET value = :value WHERE id = :id")
                  .bind("value", value)
                  .bind("id", user.id)
                  .await()
        }

}
```

Comment: As per source code it is https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/fc6480631e1b7e3be105a058583d84a17b6d92a7/spring-tx/src/main/kotlin/org/springframework/transaction/reactive/TransactionalOperatorExtensions.kt